# BLE device not detected on Moto g5 plus and lenovo k4 note

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript, android-bluetooth

Android app is detecting BLE device on selected devices only.

I compiled the code from [this](https://github.com/xiaoyaoyou1212/BLE) link also to check if phones were detecting BLE devices, and tried it on different devices.

Is there some different way to interact with BLE on some devices?

It works on my Redmi note 3(android 6), but doesn't work on Lenovo k4 note(also android 6). It doesn't work on Moto g5 plus either(android 7.0), but works on Samsung Galaxy J7(android 6). I tested the same apk on all these devices.

Location permissions are enabled on all of these devices, and the app prompts if they are not. Also, the app has both fine as well as coarse location permissions.

**NOTE:** This question is not a possible duplicate because it has location access. All the other questions here on SO addressed only that issue.

**NOTE 2:** I also read while googling about how android 7.0 doesn't allow more than 5 ble scans in 30 seconds, but that is not the issue here. I've even waited for a minute before doing so.

**NOTE 3:** Tried same with NativeScript bluetooth, same problem.

Comment: You can try to check if high precision scan is enabled on your device settings. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Andrea Ebano yes, I have it enabled. The problem would be easier if it didn't work on any device at all, or on a particular android version only. It is limited to some devices. Is this somehow also related to chipset?

Comment: Lenovo k4 note supports BLE, source: http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/4cf23938 , 

i think the problem is the pairing process. Try this:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/Moto-G5-Plus-is-not-detecting-my-Bluetooth-Headphone-of-Phillips/m-p/3615279#M343

Comment: @Andrea Ebano I know both of these devices support BLE, but they fail to detect both my weight scale and the heart rate monitor. Even the app itself shows that BLE is supported. It cannot be a problem with disconnection because the weight scale shuts down everytime, and the other phones show that devices. All the devices, when kept next to each other, only 2 show the BLE scale.

Comment: I suggest to download a ble scan application and test if the bluettoth scan works, if not works maybe your devices have some hardware issues.

Comment: @Andrea Ebano I initially couldn't connect my nativescript app, so I thought it could be some problem with native script, so I downloaded the repo in the link in the question and then tested with that, still to no avail. There's nothing in the console log that could help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused due to platform build errors since I was initially compiling the app for a lower sdk version. To fix this, the app needed to be recompiled from scratch. I used `tns platform remove android && tns run android`.